# Loggical Issue with storing UUID in both MYSQL and Oracle (Hibernate)?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, uuid

I am  looking for making my small java application to make it work with both oracle and MySQL database..I am able to achieve Inserting the UUID with Hibernate JPA in both oracle and MySQL but there are some hard coded UUID which I need to compare with database UUID (which is manually inserted).

Here is my code My entity uses..

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id; //NOTE : Here UUID datatype is java.util package
```

In Oracle I am using RAW datatype for UUID and While I fetch from entity is see data in this way....

```
  ________________________________________________________________
  Oracle         : 5C7C417E7C624D61A379DD7CA434F15D
  Java(Entity)   : 5C7C417E-7C62-4D61-A379-DD7CA434F15D
```

Here is Application behavior with MYSQL(Using binary(36) as datatype)

```
________________________________________________________________
  MYSQL         :  4193DB01AD794105AE8030DFBB44EB70
  Java(Entity)  :  34313933-6462-3031-6164-373934313035 //Whch is not similar
```

How to fetch the same UUID without dashes...in MYSQL ??   Is my approach is wrong ?

How I am fetching values from Oracle and MySQL DB.

```
@Override
    public <T extends AbsEntity> List<T> findAll(Class<T> clz) {        
        StringBuffer queryBuf = new StringBuffer();
        queryBuf.append("From " + clz.getSimpleName() + " e");
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryBuf.toString());
        List<T> result = query.getResultList();
        return result;
    }
```

> All I am doing is sysout(entity.getId());

**MAJOR UPDATE :**

> As per my analysis I am inserting the UUID using java util class
>   UUID.randomUUID() Its works fine in Oracle when I fetch I get
>   UUID(same as entered) WITHOUT dashes where as in MYSQL I get some
>   random UUID(not sure why).

```
> Later I used UUID() function of MySQL the UUID which is entered is
> again not realated(NOT SAME WITHOUT DASHASES)
```

Comment: Please edit your question with a [MCVE] including the relevant code you use to fetch values from each database.

Comment: @MT0 I have updated my Question.